# Tomcat and Logging Stacktrace Info

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, stack-trace

I'm having a very strange problem. When I log stacktraces, they seem to be originating at the line where I call the logger, rather than the line where the error occurs. This causes some serious wastes of time in terms of tracking down errors.

Using tomcat6, openjdk 6, and log4j.

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance for any help you can give.

Here are examples. Code, lines 137-142:

```
try {
    req.getContentType().trim();
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("DEBUG: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e.fillInStackTrace());
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Logs:

```
2012-01-19 10:13:25,393 [http-8080-1] ERROR com.myservlet.servlet.Servlet2  - DEBUG: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myservlet.servlet.Servlet2.doPost(Servlet2.java:140)
    at com.myservlet.servlet.Servlet2.doGet(Servlet2.java:292)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do the fill in stack trace stuff, your exception should turn up fully populated.

Simply do

```
log.error("My message", e);
```

Comment: That solved it. We do some non-container based java code, which I must have borrow that logging pattern from. For whatever reason, that pattern works for our non-container based code, but not inside tomcat.

Will have to adjust all cases sometime in the future. Thank you very much.

Comment: That pattern is NEVER appropriate for logging exceptions thrown by other bits of code, regardless of what your container or environment is. It is only appropriate where you artificially create an exception solely for the purpose of logging a stack trace for that exact point in the code.

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot more sense now. Whoever had this code before me was doing some very strange stuff w/ it. I have to jump around quite a bit between technologies and languages, so it's easy to get lost. Guess this was one of those times. :)